# UICollectionView DiffableDataSource App crashing when items are zero

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit

I am using UICollectionView with DiffableDataSource, every time my data array updates I update collectionView by calling following function:

```
func applySnapshot(animatingDifferences: Bool = true) {
        var snapshot = Snapshot()
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        snapshot.appendItems(items)
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animatingDifferences)
    }
```

The problem is my app is crashing when items count is zero. It gives following message in debugger - **"'NSLayoutConstraint constant is not finite!  That's illegal.  constant:inf firstAnchor:<NSLayoutDimension:0x282bb9100 "UIView:0x103acc180.height"> secondAnchor:(null)'"**

Can you help me solve this issue ?

Comment: The error message should give you a clue.  Look at your constraints.  The `applySnapshot` code is not relevant.